# Allow webrick server to be accessed over wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am trying to access a rails server running at `0.0.0.0:3000` on my computer from a tablet on the same wifi.

I **can connect** to regular webserver `:80`, but somehow can't get to the `:3000`.

I tried:

```
sudo ufw enable 3000
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: I think that's not the correct command to open a port in UFW. You should try [GUFW](http://gufw.org/), it simplifies a lot configuring UFW.

Comment: @Salem: would you mind making the answer as to close this question? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command to open that port would be

```
$ sudo ufw allow 3000                                     # from all hosts
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3000     # just to some subnet hosts
```

Also you can resort to `gufw`, which simplifies a lot the firewall management.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, webrick (I guess you're using `script/server`) binds only to the local interface. In order for it to be accessible from the outside, start it like this:

```
script/server -b <your-ip-address>
```

Obviously you need to enter your ethernet (or wi-fi) IP address for this to work.

Comment: in rails 3 it's `rails s -b ipaddress` but the default `0.0.0.0` is open to all, so the `-b` flag shouldn't be mandatory